# Highcharts.js Pie Chart with jQuery UI Slider - Not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I want to be able to update a Highcharts pie chart with a jQuery UI slider. I want it to go from 0% (all pieces completely hidden as they are when the page loads) to 100%.

Basically controlling that opening animation that plays automatically with a slider...

Here is my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZNB78/1/

And my CODE:

```
function updateGaugeChart(chart, value) {
    var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
    var newVal = value;
      point.update(newVal);
  }

  $(function () {
      var chartObj = {
          chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: '55%'
        }
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 20

    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [20],
            [30],
            [40]
        ]
    }]
};    

var gaugeChartObj = new Highcharts.Chart(chartObj);

var lastVal = 0;
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    step: 1,
    animate: true,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider-val").text(ui.value);
        if (Math.abs(ui.value - lastVal) > 0) {
            updateGaugeChart(gaugeChartObj, ui.value);
            lastVal = ui.value;
        }
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: What is wrong with the example?

Comment: It only collapses one of the pieces - it needs to collapse all of them and return them to their original values when moving the all the way to the right on the slider

Comment: But all of them should have the same value, or each of them should have separated selector?

Comment: No each of them should have a separated selector - separate values. So they would each start from 0 and go their respective value 20, 30, 40 etc..

Comment: So where is the problem? Only what you need is use 3 sliders and update correct point like chart.series[0].data[0] or chart.series[0].data[1] for second point.

Comment: They all have to be updated by the same slider. I tried updating the points like you suggested with one slider and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is probably a better example of what I am trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/ZNB78/5/ The legend is triggering each point on and I want the slider to do this instead. So when you get to 20% 'Right of Way' turns on, 30% 'Stringing' turns on... etc.

Comment: Someting like that? http://jsfiddle.net/ZNB78/9/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - that is perfect!